# How to display an image in a win32 application?

Tags: c++, image

I'm new to windows in c++ and i can't figure out how to display a image in my window?

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
int wmId, wmEvent;
PAINTSTRUCT ps;
HDC hdc;

switch (message)
{
case WM_COMMAND:
    wmId    = LOWORD(wParam);
    wmEvent = HIWORD(wParam);
    // Parse the menu selections:
    switch (wmId)
    {
    case IDM_ABOUT:
        DialogBox(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_ABOUTBOX), hWnd, About);
        break;
    case IDM_EXIT:
        DestroyWindow(hWnd);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    break;
case WM_PAINT:
    hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    //Display an image here.
    EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    break;
case WM_DESTROY:
    PostQuitMessage(0);
    break;
default:
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}
```

I have a .png file on my desktop with the file path of Desktop\Dirt.png. i want to display this on my window at the location of 0,0. I don't know how to do this so any help will be nice. Also a function for this would be helpful.

Comment: I'd learn C++ before trying to use the Win32 api. That task is not as simple as it seems. Refer here to get an idea: http://www.winprog.org/tutorial/

Comment: I found HBITMAP hImage = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(NULL, (LPCSTR)file, IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_LOADFROMFILE | LR_LOADTRANSPARENT);  but file is undeclared what should i do with that?

Comment: again, it is not as simple as you think. You need to learn a ton more before trying to do anything with GUI.

Comment: You need to *load* an image, get a *device context* and maybe *draw* the image using the device context.

Comment: Is there a library that will do this for me?

Comment: @MrQandA No, there's no library. You just need to call a few functions, that's all.